# update trigger to update into same table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, ora-04091

```
create or replace trigger admin.patreg_paid_amt_temp
before UPDATE OF PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP ON admin.patient_registration
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
For EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   if :new.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP != :old.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP
   then
       UPDATE admin.patient_registration d
        set d.PAID_AMOUNT = :new.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP + d.DIFFERENCE ,
        d.PENDING = ABS(:new.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP - d.DUES) 
       where d.PATIENT_ID = :new.PATIENT_ID;
   end if;
END;
```

I know it is caused because trigger cannot change the content of the table it reads from.
Can anyone please help me in accomplishing this

When i write this query following error occurs

```
update admin.patient_registration set paidamount_temp= 1000 where patient_id=11;
```

An error was encountered performing the requested operation

**ORA-04091**:table Admin.PATIENT_REGISTRATION is mutating,trigger/function may not see it
**ORA-06512**:at "ADMIN.PATREG_PAID_AMT_TEMP",line 4
**ORA-04088**: error during execution of trigger "ADMIN.PATREG_PAID_AMT_TEMP"
04091. 000000-"table %s.%s is mutating,trigger/function may not see it"

Comment: As I aid in my edit, my solution will solve your problem because PATIENT_ID is the primary key of PATIENT_REGISTRATION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can manipulate the :NEW values in a trigger:

```
if :new.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP != :old.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP
then
    :new.PAID_AMOUNT := :new.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP + :old.DIFFERENCE;
    :new.PENDING := ABS(:new.PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP - :new.DUES);
    :new.difference := :new.total_charges - :new.per_day_charges;
end if;
```

---

Now we know there is one PATIENT_REGISTRATION record per patient (i.e. PATIENT_ID is the primary key) we also know my solution wil work and you won't get a mutating table error.

Comment: The columns paid_amount and difference must change on update of paidamount_temp. The values they must store after the update of paidamount_temp is given in my question. @APC

Comment: @Akki: that's what the trigger does.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked but the difference is precalculated in the difference column. Do we still need to specify the difference over here.   @APC

Comment: @Akki - not sure what you mean by "Do we still need to specify the difference over here".  Also I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: I mean to say that if the statement :new.difference := :new.total_charges - :new.per_day_charges; . If this statement is not specifed still the trigger runs succesfully so is it necessary to keep in this trigger

Comment: I added that because it appeared in the column description you posted, plus you said it needed to be set in an earlier comment.  But seriously, these are *your* business rules.  I can't tell you whether the code is right or wrong, because I only know what you tell me.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would like to state that You should not design your logic in this way. I don't know what is *above* your trigger but it should be that *upper* layer's role to update `PAID_AMOUNT` and `PENDING` values. Putting application logic in triggers can lead only to chaos.

But. If You have no control over application above database and have to do this then You should change your trigger to be `for each statement`. Inside it create a loop to iterate over `NEW_TABLE` and update each row accordingly. But remember to put a condition on Your update like this:

```
UPDATE admin.patient_registration d
    set d.PAID_AMOUNT = p_PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP + p_DIFFERENCE 
    where d.PAID_AMOUNT != (p_PAIDAMOUNT_TEMP + p_DIFFERENCE) -- this is important
    and d.patient_id != p_patient_id
```

to prevent trigger from triggering itself.

Inside 'statement' trigger you can modify trigger's 'base' table.

[Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm) you can read more about it.

Comment: Using triggers to validate business rules which could be enforced by CHECK constraints is at least as bad a practice as putting application logic in triggers.

Comment: @APC I agree it's bud but i wouldn't put a consistent triggers based validation on the same level as trigger based logic. And I agree that in this case trigger is absolutely unnecessary for validation so I deleted that part of my post.